# Typescript: Infer functions return type's base class generic argument and use infered type for said function as argument type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need an invoker function. This function will invoke factories for class constructions of a given base class.
The base class has a generic parameter that is used as the constructors first and only argument type.

```
class ServiceBase<TArg = unknown> {
    constructor(protected arg: TArg) {}
}

class NumberService extends ServiceBase<number> {}
```

Now to the factory function. The factory function should be an inline function without any typings. It takes one Argument. The Argument type should be infered by the base class generic argument of the class that is constructed.

Example:

```
invokeFactory((arg) => new NumberService(arg))
```

Because the factory provided to `invokeFactory` returns a `NumberService` and it is extending `ServiceBase<number>` the arg needs to be infered to type `number`.

I tried to infer the Service type and Arg type, this is easy and is working. When the factory type definition types the arg as any.

Test code:

```
const invokeFactory = <
    TService extends ServiceBase,
    TArg = TService extends ServiceBase<infer T> ? T : never
>(
    factory: (arg: any /* Dont use TArg*/) => TService
): [TService, TArg] => {
    const magicArg: TArg = null!; // for simplification

    return [factory(magicArg), magicArg];
};

const [numberService, arg] = invokeFactory((x) => new NumberService(x));
```

`numberService` is infered as `NumberService` and `arg` is infered as `number`.

As soon as I explicitly specify the arg type of the function instead of using any, TService is not infered correctly:

```
const invokeFactory = <TService extends ServiceBase>(
    factory: (arg: TService extends ServiceBase<infer T> ? T : never) => TService
): [TService, TService extends ServiceBase<infer T> ? T : never] => {
    const magicArg: TService extends ServiceBase<infer T> ? T : never = null!; // for simplification

    return [factory(magicArg), magicArg];
};

const [numberService, arg] = invokeFactory((x) => new NumberService(x));
```

`numberService` is infered to `ServiceBase<unknown>` and `arg` to `unknown`

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: As far as I know there is no facility whatsoever to infer a type for a function parameter based on how it's used inside the body of the function.  See [this comment in ms/TS#15196](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15196#issuecomment-294618460).  So this is not possible. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yeah I see, that is what I thought, just wanted to make sure :) thank you very much. The only thing to add is that, I do not want to infer the paramter type by usage, it should be infered by the functions return type`s base class generic arg.

if function returns class B that extends A<number> then the parameter should be of type number.

Comment: Ah okay then it’s a different TS limitation of inference. When I get to a real computer I’ll elaborate.

Comment: So it's essentially [ms/TS#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599). In general, the return type of a function depends on the type of its input.  It happens that whatever the type of `x` is, the return type of `x => new NumberService(x)` will be a `NumberService`, but TS doesn't come to this conclusion *before* needing to know what type `x` is and therefore what `TService` is.  It's possible that some future version of TS will handle this particular case, but it's a general limitation that simultaneous generic and contextual typing often fails.

Comment: See prev comment. If that suffices I'll write up an answer, if not, let me know.

Comment: yeah, the compiler would need to evaluate from "RTL" to first infer the `TService` to something, and then construct the typings of the argument based on the infered type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation or missing feature of TypeScript; simultaneous [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument inference and [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) of function callback parameters doesn't always succeed.  Whether or not it works depends strongly on the exact order in which TypeScript analyzes the expressions.  Many common cases are handled already, but there are plenty of situations in which things go wrong.  There's a catch-all open GitHub issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599), and there has been progress, but unless TypeScript's inference algorithm is completely overhauled (see [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134)) there will always be holes like this somewhere.

---

Generally speaking the type of an expression of the form `x => f(x)` or `x => new C(x)` depends on the type of `x`. Functions and constructors can be generic or [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), and the output type can therefore depend on the input.  Right now the compiler doesn't do any more detailed analysis to determine whether or not this is actually the case for a given `f` or `C`.

You would like

```
invokeFactory(x => new NumberService(x))
```

to be analyzed as follows:

- The type of the expression `x => new NumberService(x)` depends on the type of `x`, but maybe the return type doesn't. Let's check:
- The `NumberService` constructor always produces a `NumberService` instance, regardless of its constructor arguments. (*but this analysis does not happen*)
- Therefore, yes, the expression `new NumberSevice(x)` is of type `NumberService` regardless of the type of `x`
- Therefore `x => new NumberService(x)` returns `NumberService`.
- Therefore `TService` should be inferred as `NumberService`.
- Therefore `TService extends ServiceBase<infer T> ? T : never)` is `number`.
- Therefore `x => new NumberService(x)` is of type `(arg: number) => NumberService`
- Therefore the callback parameter `x` is contextually typed as `number`.
- Therefore `new NumberService(x)` is acceptable.

Unfortunately that's not the order that things happen in.  It's more like:

- The type of the expression `x => new NumberService(x)` depends on the type of `x`, but maybe the return type doesn't depend on the input type. Let's check:
- Uh oh, the expression `new NumberService(x)` involves `x`. That's a circular dependency so I have to put off evaluation of this until I know what `x` is.
- `x` is contextually typed by `(arg: TService extends ServiceBase<infer T> ? T : never)`, so I need to evaluate that type.
- In order to do that, I need to infer `TService`.
- Oops, there are no expressions involving `TService` whose types I already know.  There is no inference site. I'll have to fallback to the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) of `ServiceBase`, equivalent to `ServiceBase<unknown>`.
- Therefore `TService extends ServiceBase<infer T> ? T : never` is of type `unknown`.
- Therefore `x` is of type `unknown`.
- Therefore `new NumberService(x)` is unacceptable.

---

Perhaps someday this situation will be improved for your particular example.  But again, the general class of problem will remain.  In any case, you'll need to handle this yourself, either by explicitly specifying the type argument like `invokeFactory<NumberService>(x => new NumberService(x))` or by explicitly annotating the callback parameter like `invokeFactory((x: number) => new NumberService(x))` or some other way to [cut the knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_Knot).